# How exactly are the number of super delegates determined for the Democratic primaries?

Tags: united-states, primaries, democratic-party

So I totally understand that the super delegates include those such as the president, vice president, senators, past presidents, etc., but I was wondering if there was an exact mathematical equation that would explain how there were 712 super delegates for the 2016 Democratic primary.

For example, how was Alabama awarded 7 super delegates of the 2016 Democratic primaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Democratic Party's super delegates come from these groups:

- Current and former POTUS, VPOTUS, DNC Chair or Democratic leader in the Senate or the House
- Current Democratic governor, senator or congressman
- Members of the Democratic National Committee

---

Since you asked about Alabama, the delegates consist of 5 DNC Members, 1 Representative and 1 national Democratic county official.

---

Basically, it can be deduced that there isn't a fixed number of super delegates. For this year's Democratic primary, there's a [list of all unpledged delegates](https://cdn1.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/6622695/Unpledged_Delegate_List_5.27.16.0.pdf).

This [article by Vox](http://www.vox.com/policy-and-politics/2016/2/22/11070364/list-all-superdelegates) explains the concept of super delegates clearly.

Unfortunately, there isn't any equation apart from the composition of super delegates.